# Is there a way to use scanf with the "if" and "else" statements?

Tags: c, scanf

I have to create and call a function from main. Then I have to call scanf to read two integers and print out the bigger one. Then I have to do another scanf, but this time with doubles instead of integers.

```
int main()
{
   int x, y;
   scanf("%d%d", &x, &y);

   if (x > y)
   {
      printf("%d", x);
   }

   scanf("%lf%lf", &w, &z);

   if ( w > z)
   {
      printf("%f", w);
   }

   return 0;
}
```

I'm not sure if I did this right and how would I check the return value to see that the scanf worked? Thanks.

Comment: if return value of scanf == no of args you passed then its a success else error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, you can check whether `scanf()` has worked succesfully or not as follows,

```
if( scanf("%d%d", &x, &y) == 2)
{
   if (x > y)
   {
       printf("%d", x);
   }
}
else
{
   printf("\nFailure");
}
```

`scanf()` returns the number of arguments successfuly read by it.

Answer (score 2):

```
how would I check the return value to see that the scanf worked?
```

By checking the return value of scanf().

```
  if( scanf("%d%d", &x, &y) != 2) 
  {
   /* input error */ 
  }

   if (x > y)
   {
      printf("%d", x);
   }

   if(scanf("%lf%lf", &w, &z) != 2) 
   { 
   /* input error */
   }

   if ( w > z)
   {
      printf("%f", w);
   }
```

From [scanf()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) documentation:

```
   These functions return the number of input items successfully matched
   and assigned, which can be fewer than provided for, or even zero in
   the event of an early matching failure.

   The value EOF is returned if the end of input is reached before
   either the first successful conversion or a matching failure occurs.
   EOF is also returned if a read error occurs, in which case the error
   indicator for the stream (see ferror(3)) is set, and errno is set
   indicate the error.
```

Answer (score 0):

It says you're trying to call a function from main.  Does that mean that your teacher wants a function besides main?  In which case you want to create one as below.  You will also have to do something similar only with double integers.

```
#include stdio.h

int bigger(void);

int main(void)
{
int larger;
larger = bigger(void);
printf("The Larger integer is: %d\n", larger);

return 0;
}

int bigger(void)
{
int x,y,z;
printf("Enter your first integer\n");
scanf("%d", &x);
printf("Enter your second integer\n");
scanf("%d", &x);

if(x > y)
{
z = x;
}
else
{
z = y;
}
return z;
}
```

Comment: OH! Nice catch, thanks! Yeah, I have to create a function named "read_example". :) Thanks!

Comment: What if I only create one function?? And when he says "Add a scanf to read two doubles...", does that mean add another function for the doubles? I'm a bit confused because in the directions, he only told us to make one function called "read_example". :(

Comment: You can do everything from one function, even print the greater of the two integers.

I would just create the function as void read_example(void);
Then you can do both the double and int scanf and prints in one function.

Comment: So, could I write the function to include both the conditions for the integers AND the doubles? :D

Comment: I don't see why not!  Programming is very open, you can do whatever it allows you to do.  You just won't have any return statement in the function.

Comment: Oh, one quick question, so in main, when I'm printing out the number, since I have both doubles and integers in the function I'm calling...would I have to do two separate printf statements? (One for if the answer is an integer and one for if it's a double)

Comment: You can do everything within the same print f statement, or in seperate ones if you like, its all personal preference.

Ex:
int inum;
double dnum;
printf("The larger double is: %lf, the larger integer is %d\n", dnum, i num);

Answer (score 0):

sollution for

I have to create and call a function from main. Then I have to call scanf to read two integers and print out the bigger one. Then I have to do another scanf, but this time with doubles instead of integers.*/

```
   #include<stdio.h>
   #include<stdlib.h>

   int main(){
   int a,b;
   printf("enter any two numbers");
   scanf(" %d\n %d",&a,&b);
   if(a>b){
        printf("bigger number is %d",a);
        }else{
              printf("bigger number is %d\n",b);        
               }    
    float c,d;
    printf("enter any two numbers");
    scanf(" %f\n %f",&c,&d);
    if(c>d){
      printf("bigger number is %.2f",c);
      }else{
          printf("bigger number is %.2f\n",d);        
              }               
   system("pause");
   return 0;`
    }
```